# iOS UITests Assert UITextFiled'text failed

Tags: ios, testing, xcode-ui-testing

```
XCTAssertTrue(textField.exists, @"TextField is not exist");
[textField tap];
[textField typeText:@"123"];

XCUIElement *textField2 = [[element childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeTextField] elementBoundByIndex:1];

[textField2 tap];

XCTAssertTrue(textField2.exists, @"TextField2 is not exist");

[textField2 tap];

[textField2 typeText:@"123"];

XCTAssertEqual(textField2.value, @"123", @"account is not correct");
```

error message:

> ((textField2.value) equal to (@"123")) failed:("<12333303 000000a0>")
>   is not equal to ("") - account is not correct
>   [app.buttons[@"\u767b\u5f55"] tap];

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: I don't how to famat my code sorry!!!

Comment: Please add a question. I don't see a question.

Comment: sorry , this is my first post question here  ， I have worked out.  NSString used the method stringValue, so...

Comment: try `XCTAssert([textField2.value isEqualToString: @"123"], @"account is not correct");`